# Why does Dart (not) match this RegEx?

Tags: regex, dart

I have got this small bit of code:

```
void main() {
    RegExp re = new RegExp(r".*(a+)+\d");
    print("a0aaaaaaaaaaaaa".contains(re));
    print("a0aaaaaaaaaaaaaa".contains(re));
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

Why? I would expect both to be true.

Edit:
I filed a bug report:
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19193

Comment: We expect this bug to be fixed, starting with Dart 1.9.

Comment: This is an example of a regexp with catastrophic backtracking.  The "+" inside the other "+" is the problem.  See http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is definitely a bug.

It might be a common and deliberate bug in JS RegExp implementations. If a RegExp runs for "too long", some implementations give up and claim not to match.

I'm guessing (because I haven't checked yet) that it is the VM's RegExp implementation that bails out because the RegExp is taking too long to complete. The RegExp in question looks exactly like one that would cause catastrophic backtracking (taking up to exponential time in the length of the input). That would explain why increasing the length causes it to suddenly give up and say that it doesn't match, even though clearly it should.

Answer (score 2):

Can't **reproduce** your result using [Try Dart](http://try.dartlang.org/) online compiler, they both do successfully return `true`, but it does return `true` and `false` using another [Dart compiler](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_dart_online.php).

Try using the following instead.

```
RegExp re = new RegExp(r"(a+)\d");
```

Comment: it reproduces in `Dart VM version: 1.4.0 (Tue May 20 04:56:35 2014) on "linux_x64"` the latest dart in arch linux.

Comment: that is strange. I have to look over my installation.

Comment: I could remove `+`, but this does not explain the behaviour. BTW my platform is also linux: `Dart VM version: 1.4.2 (Tue May 27 03:00:04 2014) on "linux_x64"`

Comment: If you are running try.dartlang.org in Chrome, the RegExp will be run using the V8 regexp engine. That regexp engine has been built to not give up on a regexp, even if it takes incredibly long to compute (instead it is hooked into the browsers normal "script is running too long" warning, so you can abort it like any other part of the JS script). That's probably why it gives the correct result for this regexp, where the VM gives up early.